# Question about entire functions and Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have encountered a problem in complex analysis:

> "Is there an entire function $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(z) = 1$ whenever $|z|>1$? Justify your answer."

I know that it must have something to do with Liouville's Theorem, I just don't see it, can someone help me?

Comment: An entire function is expressible as a Taylor series around any point. Here $f$ is flat on most of the plane so all the higher derivatives at say $z=2$ are zero which implies $f$ is constant, contradicting $f(0)=0$

Comment: If you absolutely want to use Lioville you can do that. Divide the plane into two parts: $|z|\leq 1$ and $|z|>1$. Argue why $f$ has to be bounded on the compact region $|z|\leq 1$. For $|z|>1$ you already know that $f$ is bounded. Combind these facts with Lioville to reach a conclusion.

Comment: using the Taylor series is very enlightening, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Liouville's Theorem it is straightforward. The function is bounded  by 1 since

1) |f(z)|=1 when |z|>=1.
2) |f(z)|<=1 when |z|<=1 (  Principle of Maximum)

So f(z) should be a constant, but it is not. So it does not exist

Comment: I think I got it by using Taylor's series around 0 and take radius greater than 1 can go to infinite combined with Cauchy's Inequality (using the same radius) and Liouville's thm.
thank you